# Cpanel - Cannot execute Joomla Friendly URL and Python Application after adding .htaccess

Tags: python, .htaccess, joomla, cpanel

I have **hosted Joomla website in public_html** folder and set User friendly URL for all sub menus in the website. For that I made a joomla admin settings and also kept .htaccess file to remove index.php [sample **https://arsenalit.com/index.php/services/web-design-development** ] in the url in the public_html folder to work. it is working : sample url : **https://arsenalit.com/services/web-design-development** .

Followed by I created Python application from cpanel called ait-tools. and wrote the flask app.py with two api urls, one is root / and another is /json.

Now when I try to execute this as

https://arsenalit.com/ait-tools - **working**
https://arsenalit.com/ait-tools/json - **NOT working**

Key Points

1. I have added .htaccess in the ait-tools folder - NOT WORKING
2. I have modifed public_html/.htaccess file itself with different settings - NOT WORKING
3. If i **remove the .htaccess file, Now xxx/ait-tools/json is working but Joomla website user friendly not working**.

PLEASE HELP ME, IT WILL HELP ME TO PROVIDE LOT OF FREE LIBRARIES TO OUR SOFTWARE COMMUNITY.

Reference URL

https://www.joomlart.com/tutorials/joomla-tutorials/joomla-4-tutorials-how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls

[Python flask app routing in cpanel: can only access root url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106913/python-flask-app-routing-in-cpanel-can-only-access-root-url/63971427#63971427)

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and post your Joomla content there.

Answer (score 0):

I got to work by adding the below lines in .htaccess file.

```
## Begin - Python ! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteEngine on
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ait-tools
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule ^http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE]
#RewriteRule . /ait-tools/ [L]

#
## End - Python ! core SEF Section.
```

Hope somebody will use of it.

Comment: Please award your own answer the green tick to mark this page as resolved.