# deploying simple flask app on shared hosting using cpanel, but only root url can access,

Tags: python, .htaccess, flask, cpanel

I am having trouble deploying a Flask application on a shared hosting server using cpanel. The home page (subdomain.domain.com) is loading correctly, but when I click on other links such as "Contact Us" or "About Us (subdomain.domain.com/about-us)," I am getting a "404 URL Not Found" error.
The project structure is as follows: the root folder contains a "website" folder, which contains a "Templates," "static," "init.py," "views.py," and "auth.py" files. Additionally, there is an "app.py" and "passenger_wsgi.py" file in the root folder.

in templates i am using {{ url_for('views.aboutus') }}                                                                                                                              My home page is loading but if i click on other pages i am getting 404 url

my question is similar: [Python flask app routing in cpanel: can only access root url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106913/python-flask-app-routing-in-cpanel-can-only-access-root-url)
any answer is not working for me
this is my project structure:

```
|-->root folder
      |--->website
              |-->Templates
              |-->static
              |-->__init__.py
              |-->views.py
              |-->auth.py
      |-->app.py
      |-->passenger_wsgi.py
```

i tried to change .htaccess file but still it is not working

This is my .htaccess file:-

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN

PassengerAppRoot "/home/user/public_html/subdomain.domain.com"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/user/virtualenv/public_html/subdomain.domain.com/3.8/bin/python"
PassengerAppLogFile "/home/user/public_html/subdomain.domain.com/error.log"

# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} \[END,NE\]
RewriteRule ^(static/.\*)$ - \[L\]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

passenger_wsgi.py file:

```
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
from app import app as application
```

app.py file :

```
from website import createApp

app = createApp()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**init**.py file inside the website folder:

```
import os

from flask import Flask


def createApp():
    app = Flask(__name__)
        
    # static folder route
    app.static_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/')
    
    # temlates folder route
    app.template_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/')

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/auth/')
    return app
```

and my views.py is:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)


@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
    # return "<h4>Hello</h4>"


@views.route('/about-us',methods=['GET'])
def aboutus():
    # return render_template('about.html')
    return "<h4>Hello</h4>"
    


@views.route('services/')
def services():
    return render_template('services.html')
```

when i go to subdomain.domain.com my Home page i loading. but if i click on other page url i am getting 404 url not found, it is working perfectelly on localhost

Comment: Have you looked at what the URLs are rendered as using "view page source"?

Comment: on view page source it is showing <a href="/about-us">About Us</a> , when i click on /about-us,          'https://subdomain.domain.com/passenger_wsgi.py/about-us'  is rendering @roganjosh

Comment: Please check the formatting in your question of the .htaccess file. As posted it does not make sense… check the spacing and there are spurious backslash escapes (that would otherwise result in a 500 error). It is also incomplete (and combining with the next line of text) as written.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help you.

Change your passenger_wsgi.py file to:

```
import imp
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'app.py')
application = wsgi.app
```

and change app.py to:

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()
application = app
```

This is because WSGI software usually used to run Python on servers requires the main application variable to be called application. Of course this depends on the hosting server.

I hope this helps

Comment: I have attempted to solve my issue using this method, but unfortunately it has not yet been successful. 
is my .htaccess file correct?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my .htaccess file and it resolved the issue

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN

PassengerAppRoot "/home/user/public_html/subdomain.domain.com"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/user/virtualenv/public_html/subdomain.domain.com/3.8/bin/python"
PassengerAppLogFile "/home/user/public_html/subdomain.domain.com/error.log"

# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(static/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Those mode_rewrite directives don't really make sense - they aren't doing anything?!